# Toastr js with Master content pages in UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, toastr

I have included Toastr.js file for notifications in my project but it does not seems to work in content page with update panel. What's the solution for this issue?

I am calling the below static function from my content pages which is running perfectly on pages where I have not used Update Panel.

I search and found that one need to re initialize the js function on page post back occurs and you can use `sys.webforms.pagerequestmanager` for this? I dont know how to implement this and where exactly? Can anyone help me on this.

```
public static void ShowMessage(this Page page, string message, string title, string type = "info")
{
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "toastr_message",
          String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}', '{2}');", type.ToLower(), message, title), addScriptTags: true);
}
```

Comment: If you are using updatepanel then try `page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "toastr_message", String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}', '{2}');", type.ToLower(), message, title), True);`

Comment: No alert even with RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: try `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "toastr_message", String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}', '{2}');", type.ToLower(), message, title), True);`